# Transitive runtime dependencies are discarded when packing project, causing runtime failure

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package

Project A (.NET Standard 2.0) has a method that uses [TestServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.testhost.testserver), so it has a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost`. It is built into a NuGet package.

Project B (.NET Standard 2.0) has a reference to the NuGet package from A. It is also built into a NuGet package.

Project C (.NET Core 2.2) is an XUnit test project, that has a reference to NuGet package B. It has a single test that calls the method from A.

All these projects compile successfully. But when the test from C is run, it fails with the following:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

If I manually add a reference to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` to C, the test executes successfully. But from my understanding of .NET and how it handles transitive dependencies, this shouldn't be necessary.

Am I wrong, or is something broken here?

Comment: Can you show `<PackageReference>` of TestHost package from the ProjectA.csproj?

Comment: @DarjanBogdan It's bog-standard: `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting" Version="2.2.0" />`

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking you have defined <PrivateAssets> or similar [tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets), which would explain such behavior. If you have .nuspec file, could you check if it's defined `developmentDependency` on TestHost package?

Comment: @DarjanBogdan Nope, nothing special - all the packages refs were added via the VS2017 NuGet Package Manager UI, none of them have any child nodes.

Comment: Does ProjectA's nuget package has Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost enlisted in the list of dependencies (when using NuGetPackageExplorer or VisualStudio's Package Explorer? As you said, it should work out of the box, if dependency chain is correctly defined.

Comment: @DarjanBogdan Aha, there are no dependencies listed for package A by those NuGet tools! But if I download that NuGet package and open the DLL with ILSpy, the dependencies are listed correctly. I don't have a nuspec file with explicit dependencies listed for package A - everything is in the csproj - but I was under the impression the tooling would figure this out for me.

Comment: I just realized that you've shown wrong package reference (`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting`), so please add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.TestHost` as a package reference, if not already there. Right now, it looks like that particular DLL was referenced manually, so package reference should be inside csproj if you want tool to wrap up everything automatically. Also, manually added references could be part of nuget package, but you need to use .nuspec and manually specify them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I figured out the problem, thanks to the assistance of @Darjan Bogdan.

Originally, project A was a .NET Framework project with `packages.config` and `project.nuspec` files, built into a package by running `nuget pack project.nuspec` during our build pipeline.

I then "upgraded" project A to .NET Standard 2.0 ("upgraded" = recreated it from scratch) and deleted the now-unnecessary `packages.config` and `project.nuspec` files, and changed the pack command to use the project file instead: `nuget pack project.csproj`. Because it continued to build successfully, I assumed everything was fine.

But I didn't know one important thing: Microsoft's NuGet team updated their tool to support the new-format `csproj` files, [yet didn't bother to support the `PackageReference` element](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4491). The net result is that `nuget pack` on a new-format project succeeds and produces a `nupkg` file, but that file has no dependencies listed, which is an absolutely terrible time-wasting user experience.

So I have now changed our build pipeline to use `dotnet pack` instead and the dependencies come through as expected, and everything Just Works.